# Unknown http error with http request to an iis server with ionic

Tags: http, iis, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I've got a problem with my ionic app. I try to get a json object from my iis (asp.NET) server. But the request doesn't even come into my controller. Everytime, i get the same error:

> http failure response for (unknown url) 0 unknown error

At first, I thought it was just a cors problem so i fixed it but now, it works with chrome and internet explorer 11 but not with edge and, more important, it doesn't work on device.
I don't think the problem is with my typescript code since there is no problem with a Google request... But, just in case, there is my code:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:60196', {withCredentials : true}).subscribe(data => {
  this.testData = JSON.stringify(data);
}, err => {
  this.testData = JSON.stringify(err);
});
```

For the record: my `iis` server use windows impersonation and my app must run on windows devices (i didn't try my code with android or ios devices).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have a No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error ?

Comment: Actuallay, i don't get any detail on the error. It's just an "unknown error"

Comment: On Edge, the only information i can get from the error is that is loaded by the cache (weird since it never loaded in another way and it say that even if i clean the cache)

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't work on device

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:60196', {withCredentials : true}).subscribe(data => {
  this.testData = JSON.stringify(data);
}, err => {
  this.testData = JSON.stringify(err);
});
```

Get request is rerencing to **localhost**. Here should be some Api endpoint when testing it on device...